# how to check with ioredis if the a connection was established to the redis server?

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I'm writing a nodejs 5.10.1 application, and i connect to a redis-server.

i'm using the ioredis nodejs module from https://github.com/luin/ioredis.

I can't seem to figure out how to check if a connection was established to the server.

the code to connect to a redis server is pretty simple:

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
```

the documentation states the following under Connection Events

```
You can also check out the Redis#status property to get the current connection status.
```

don't really understand what it means or how to work with it. any ideas ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of the properties of the redis object you started is the `status`:

`console.log(redis.status)` will give you the current , in my case it says : `connecting`

Comment: I dont think status is giving correct result. I tried with random IP; it failed to connect but status is still showing connecting